# Angularfire2. Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I'm trying to separate the logic from my components to a service, it works but still I'm getting console errors.

I'm constructing this service and consuming it in my component

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DatabaseService {
  public businessDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Business>;
  public business: Observable<Business>;

  constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.auth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      this.uid = user.uid;
      this.businessDoc = this.db.doc<Business>(this.businessAddress);
      this.business = this.businessDoc.valueChanges()
    }
  }
  private get businessAddress() {
    return 'users/' + this.uid
  }
}
```

And this is my component

```
export class ConfigComponent implements OnInit {

  config: Config;

  constructor(public db: DatabaseService) {
    this.db.business.subscribe(res => {
      this.config = res.config;
    });
  }
```

Finally, in my template

```
<input [ngModel]="config?.regular" (ngModelChange)="onConfigChange($event)">
```

It compiles with no problem, as you can see it even renders properly in the view, but then in the browser console I get this:

[image: Console error]

If I initialize the the business observable in my service, like this `public business: Observable<Business> = new Observable()`, I don't get the error anymore, but then the component doesn't display anything

As I understand it, `business` does not yet exist in the service because it's either waiting for  `businessDoc` to connect or for it's own 'valueChanges' so it's indeed undefined when the component tries to access it; and that's why initializing it solves the error log, but messes with the view.

What's the proper way to do this? Thanks!

Edit #1:

When I move my `subscribe` from the component constructor to `ngOnInit` it stops rendering

[image]

Edit #2:

I began trying things, including leaving open my Firestore, so I deleted the line where I subscribe to `authState` and It began working. This won't work in production, but I think the problem is in my auth subscription, not where I first tough

```
constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFirestore) {
// this.auth.authState.subscribe(user => {
    this.uid = "twCTRUpXvYRiYGknXn6j7fe0mvj2";
    this.businessDoc = db.doc<Business>(this.businessAddress);
    this.business = this.businessDoc.valueChanges()
 // });
}

private get businessAddress() {
    return 'users/' + this.uid
}
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer regarding your edit :)

Comment: For 1 thing you should move the logic in the constructor of your `ConfigComponent` to the method `ngOnInit`, that is where it belongs. The problem seems that `this.businessDoc.valueChanges();` is not returning an observable. Place a breakpoint before/after that line and check the returned value.

Comment: @igor weirdly when I move this to ngOnInit it stops rendering, and I get the same error

Comment: do you have a `@Injectable()` on your `DatabaseService`?

Comment: @PierreDuc Yes I do. i have `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})`

Comment: Feels like you are injecting the wrong `DatabaseService`. Also, even though that's not the issue here, it's better to use the async pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code as it is written expects the `authState` to resolve synchronously. That call is asynchronous and thus a call to a state that is set *after* that resolves will return `undefined` (or whatever the default/initial value is).

There are many ways to resolve this, the one I chose is to add an `initialize` method to the service that returns an observable that can be subscribed to by a component. This will resolve once `authState` resolves. I used [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) so that the call will only ever resolve a single time successfully and will then replay the result to any subsequent subscriptions. The `tap` operator allows the state to be set on the service without subscribing directly to the observable.

---

**DatabaseService.ts**

```
import { tap, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DatabaseService {
  public businessDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Business>;
  public business: Observable<Business>;
  private readonly _initialize: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this._initialize = this.auth.authState.pipe(tap(user => {
        this.uid = user.uid;
        this.businessDoc = this.db.doc<Business>(this.businessAddress);
        this.business = this.businessDoc.valueChanges()
    }), shareReplay());
  }

  initialize() : Observable<any> {
    return this._initialize;
  }

  private get businessAddress() {
    return 'users/' + this.uid
  }
}
```

**ConfigComponent.ts**

```
export class ConfigComponent implements OnInit {

  config: Config;

  constructor(private readonly db: DatabaseService){ }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.db.initialize().subscribe(() => {
      this.db.business.subscribe(res => {
        this.config = res.config;
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks, but could you elaborate please? I was under the impression that by subscribing to `authState` it would resolve asynchronously. Or what would be other methods to solve this?

Comment: @Darkade - In your code it did resolve asynchronously but *after* the constructor of the `ConfigComponent` (as well as the `ngOnInit` call) were executed which means that the state of the service was not set at the moment where the `ConfigComponent` was accessing it. The "new" code allows the component to wait on the state being initialized (ie. the call back from `authstate` happening).

Answer (score 0):

No idea what's going wrong, but let me suggest you another way of putting it down, maybe that will work:

service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DatabaseService {
  private businessAddress: string = "business"

  public businessDoc = this.af.doc<Business>(this.businessAddress);
  public business = this.businessDoc.valueChanges();

  constructor(readonly af: AngularFirestore) {}
}
```

component:

```
export class ConfigComponent implements OnInit {

  config$: Observable<Config> = this.db.business.pipe(
    map((res) => res && res.config)
  );

  constructor(readonly db: DatabaseService) {}
}
```

template:

```
<input [ngModel]="(config$ | async)?.regular" (ngModelChange)="onConfigChange($event)">
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, and I realized I neglected to put something in my question that's causing this behavior. I'm also doing some user auth. When I delete my subscribe from auth, i stop seeing the error.